# Cannot add multiple API Endpoints of the same Method in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda with a DEV and PROD alias, and am trying to setup the API Endpoint on the Lambda to point to a PUT on a DEV and PROD stage of my API Gateway. I can successfully add and test the DEV/PUT endpoint, but when I try to add an endpoint on the PROD lambda, and select the PROD API stage, it won't let me choose the PUT method for the endpoint? I assume this is because I have the DEV/PUT already assigned? I can understand not letting one method point to multiple lambdas, but this is for two different stages? Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so looks like this might just be a UI restriction. I was able to use the CLI to "aws lambda add-permission" for my API Endpoints, to each lambda function:alias combination which allows them to invoke the lambda functions.

eg.

```
aws lambda add-permission --function-name arn:aws:lambda:<REGION>:<ID>:function:<LAMBDA_NAME>:${stageVariables.lambdaAlias} --source-arn arn:aws:execute-api:<REGION>:<ID>:<API_ID>/*/GET/* --principal apigateway.amazonaws.com --statement-id <STATEMENT_ID> --action lambda:InvokeFunction
```

This was suggested by the UI when I edited the Integration Request on the API Gateway Method, and inserted the ${stageVariables.lambdaAlias}.

Comment: Yep this would just be a UI thing. The CLI command you posted is good except I think the source arn might have an extra * character? Wouldn't it be --source-arn arn:aws:execute-api:<REGION>:<ID>:<API_ID>/*/GET/* meaning any GET method in API_ID on any stage. The last segment is the resource path so it's not necessary to go multiple levels of wildcards unless some part is static.

Comment: In my case, this reflects the depth of the resources, eg. /entity/{var}/{var} as my valid API endpoint, which actually generated "*/GET/entity/*/*". In general though, you are correct and that is good to know (still learning this stuff). I'll edit the answer.